# pandas DataFrame value_counts on column that stores DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to use `value_counts()` on a pandas DataFrame column that stores another DataFrame.
Is there a possibility to get the `value_counts()` function working (or something similar), without having to transform my DataFrames to Strings or Hashes or something like that?

I've tried to count the inner DataFrames, which completely breaks, and then I tried with Arrays, which it seems it cannot make the correct comparison also:

```
# importing pandas 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
# Creating Arrys
ar1 = np.array([11,22])
ar2 = np.array([11,22])
ar3 = np.array([33,44])

df = pd.DataFrame([
  ['0', ar1], 
  ['1', ar2],
  ['2', ar3]
], columns =['str', 'ars'])

print(df["ars"].value_counts())
```

**Expected**:
[11, 22]    2
[33, 44]    1
**Actual**:
[11, 22]    1
[11, 22]    1
[33, 44]    1

```
# importing pandas 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
 
# Creating Arrys
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [11], 'col2': [22]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [11], 'col2': [22]})
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [33], 'col2': [44]})

df = pd.DataFrame([
  ['0', df1], 
  ['1', df2],
  ['2', df3]
], columns =['str', 'dfs'])

print(df["dfs"].value_counts())
```

**Expected**:
{}    2
{}    1
**Actual**:
BREAKS COMPLETELY

How can I achive the count of complex values in a DataFrame?

Comment: `print(df["ars"].value_counts())` in the second example should be `print(df["dfs"].value_counts())` maybe?

Comment: My guess is that `value_counts` knows how to evaluate the the equivalence of some objects (like strings) and not others (like `np` arrays). It might default then to a memory address or some other signature that may differ for two different arrays even though they contain the same exact values.

Comment: @jch true, that was a copy paste error - I edited it & thx for the input

Comment: When I tried your second example with `print(df["dfs"].value_counts())` it did not completely break.

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly confused how either of those managed to run without raising an exception.

Neither `np.array` nor `pd.DataFrame` are hashable, and as far as I understood, hashing was necessary for `value_count`.

Case and point, neither of your examples can be translated to their [`DataFrame.value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html#pandas-dataframe-value-counts) equivalent, because underneath it's doing `df.groupby(["ars"], dropna=True).grouper.size()` which requires hashing.

```py
>>> df.value_counts(["ars"])

TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

Overall, I would not count on any `.value_count` method working on non-hashable columns.